# Loop through list of files in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I compiling my C source files with this code:

```
CC=clang -std=c11
CFLAGS=-Wall -g
ASSEMBLY=-S -masm=intel
OPTIMIZE=-Ofast

FOLDER_SRC=./src/
FOLDER_BIN=./bin/
FOLDER_ASSEMBLY=./ass/

clean:
  rm -f \
  $(FOLDER_BIN)1.1-hello $(FOLDER_ASSEMBLY)1.1-hello \
  $(FOLDER_BIN)1.2-fahrenheit $(FOLDER_ASSEMBLY)1.2-fahrenheit \
  $(FOLDER_BIN)1.2-fahrenheit-floating $(FOLDER_ASSEMBLY)1.2-fahrenheit-floating

all:
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OPTIMIZE) $(FOLDER_SRC)1.1-hello.c -o $(FOLDER_BIN)1.1-hello
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OPTIMIZE) $(FOLDER_SRC)1.2-fahrenheit.c -o $(FOLDER_BIN)1.2-fahrenheit
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OPTIMIZE) $(FOLDER_SRC)1.2-fahrenheit-floating.c -o $(FOLDER_BIN)1.2-fahrenheit-floating

assembly:
  $(CC) $(ASSEMBLY) $(OPTIMIZE) $(FOLDER_SRC)1.1-hello.c -o $(FOLDER_ASSEMBLY)1.1-hello
  $(CC) $(ASSEMBLY) $(OPTIMIZE) $(FOLDER_SRC)1.2-fahrenheit.c -o $(FOLDER_ASSEMBLY)1.2-fahrenheit
  $(CC) $(ASSEMBLY) $(OPTIMIZE) $(FOLDER_SRC)1.2-fahrenheit-floating.c -o $(FOLDER_ASSEMBLY)1.2-fahrenheit-floating
```

I try to implement some kind of loop to write less. I added this code, but it just generating errors:

```
FILENAME_SRC := $(wildcard $(FOLDER_SRC)*.c)
FILENAME_BUILD := $(patsubst $(FOLDER_SRC)%.c,%,$(FILENAME_SRC))

echo : $(FILENAME_SRC)
  @echo $^
  @echo $(FILENAME_BUILD)

build : $(FILENAME_SRC)
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OPTIMIZE) $^ -o $(FILENAME_BUILD)
```

`make echo` printing this to the console:

```
$ make echo
src/1.2-fahrenheit.c src/1.1-hello.c src/1.2-fahrenheit-floating.c
1.2-fahrenheit 1.1-hello 1.2-fahrenheit-floating
```

`make build` command generating this error:

```
$ make build
clang -std=c11 -Wall -g -Ofast src/1.2-fahrenheit.c src/1.1-hello.c src/1.2-fahrenheit-floating.c -o 1.2-fahrenheit 1.1-hello 1.2-fahrenheit-floating
clang.exe: error: no such file or directory: '1.1-hello'
clang.exe: error: no such file or directory: '1.2-fahrenheit-floating'
make: *** [Makefile:21: build] Error 1
```

I want the expected output to look like when I do `make all`:

```
$ make all
clang -std=c11 -Wall -g -Ofast ./src/1.1-hello.c -o ./bin/1.1-hello
clang -std=c11 -Wall -g -Ofast ./src/1.2-fahrenheit.c -o ./bin/1.2-fahrenheit
clang -std=c11 -Wall -g -Ofast ./src/1.2-fahrenheit-floating.c -o ./bin/1.2-fahrenheit-floating
```

**Final solution**

```
CC := clang -std=c11
GCC := gcc -std=c11
CFLAGS := -Wall -g
ASSEMBLY := -Wall -S -masm=intel
OPTIMIZE := -O3 -march=native

SRC := $(wildcard src/*.c)
BIN := $(patsubst src/%.c,bin/%,$(SRC))
ASS := $(patsubst src/%.c,ass/%,$(SRC))

clean:
  rm -f bin/* ass/*

build: $(BIN)
$(BIN): bin/%: src/%.c
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OPTIMIZE) $^ -o $@

assembly: $(ASS)
$(ASS): ass/%: src/%.c
  $(CC) $(ASSEMBLY) $(OPTIMIZE) $^ -o $@
```

Really sorry for the `clean ass/*` though, it cannot be called `assembly` because the similar folder name in the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `all` rule needs to look something like

```
CC := clang
CFLAGS := -std=c11 -Wall -g -Ofast

targets := bin/1.1-hello bin/1.2-fahrenheit bin/1.2-fahrenheit-floating

.PHONY: all
all: $(targets)
$(targets): bin/%: src/%.c
    $(LINK.c) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

Comment: This exact code creatint the following error message: `make: *** No rule to make target 'src/1.2-farenheit.c', needed by 'bin/1.2-farenheit'.  Stop.`

Comment: Why `targets := $(wildcard bin/*.c)` not responding to re-compile a modified source file, but your solution does?

Comment: I ignored `.PHONY` and `wildcard` works similar to your solution.